# how to write data to certain columns using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe

my_template.xlsx has the following structure

```
a | b | c 
---------
```

I need to insert the data only in "a" and "c" coulmn

Here is my code, but it is wrong:

```py
reports = reports.query(FSSP_MAIN).filter_by(id=id).all()
reports_df = pd.Dataframe(data=([report.id, report.surname] for report in reports), columns = ['a', 'c'])
excel_template = 'my_template.xlsx'
with pd.ExcelWriter(excel_template, if_sheet_exists="overlay", mode="a", engine="openpyxl") as writer:
    reports_df.to_excel(
        writer,
        start_row=1
        index=False,
        header =  False
    )
```

It inserts to "a" and "b" columns, but I need to insert to "a" and "c".

I need to insert data to "a" and "c" columns in Excel.

Comment: welcome to SO, read notice to get answer : [mre]

Comment: Try to write the columns separately and specify the right `startcol` for each.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is the following:

```
import pandas as pd

reports = [{'id': 1, 'occupation':'data specialist','surname': 'Smith'}, {'id': 2, 'occupation':'data enthusiast', 'surname': 'Johnson'}]

reports_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
reports_df['a'] = [report['id'] for report in reports]
reports_df['c'] = [report['surname'] for report in reports]

excel_template = 'template.xlsx'

with pd.ExcelWriter(excel_template, if_sheet_exists="overlay", mode="a", engine="openpyxl") as writer:
    reports_df.to_excel(writer, startrow=1, index=False, header=False)
```

which will give you what you wanted

[image]